# Alt+Shift (keyboard layout hotkey) has stopped working in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, input-languages

After upgrading to Windows 10, I can no longer switch my keyboard layout with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

I have tried setting it in the "Language bar" settings, but it appears to have no effect. On the other hand, the <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key combo seems to change the layout, but is super inconvenient, because:

1. I'm used to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. Pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>  brings up the start menu and messes up the focus.

How can I get my <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> hotkey working again?